# ggplot2 heatmap, color scale with conditions

Tags: r, graph, scale, heatmap

I need to change the colors of the scale of a ggplot in R.
My table is:

```
tt<-data.frame(C1=c(0.4,.5,.5, 0, .8,.8),C2=c(.5,.6,.7, 0, .7,.8), C3=c(.8,.7,.9, 0, .8,.7), 
  C4=c(rep(0,6)), C5=c(0.4,.6,.6, 0, .8,.8),C6=c(0.8,.7,.5, 0, .8,.8), C7=c(0.8,.6,.4, 0, .8,.8))

row.names(tt)<-paste("F", 1:6, sep='')
tt<-as.matrix(tt)
```

Then  I do the reshape:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
tt_melt <- melt(tt)
tt_melt
colnames(tt_melt)<-c('fila', 'columna', 'performance')
```

And my graph is a representation of a call center and a metric related to each position:

```
ggplot(data=tt_melt,
       aes(x=columna, y=fila, fill=performance)) + geom_tile() + 
  geom_text(aes(label=performance), color='white') 
+ theme_minimal(base_size = 12, base_family = "")+
labs(title = 'Performance por posicion en el call')+
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red","yellow", "green"))
scale_fill_gradient(low = "yellow",  high = "darkgreen")
```

[image]

But it doesn't take the scale. I need to get the 0s in white (because it means that there's nobody in that space) and the rest from red to green. So it's not a truly continuous scale (but should be continuous from red to green).
How can I make ggplot take the scale? Also, how can I create a scale that has a condition over the values? And finally, if there's a better way to do this I would be glad to hear about it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope the code formatting is an artifact of the SO paste. I prefer more structured ggplot builds.

You can have far more control if you generate discrete breaks:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2) 

tt <- data.frame(C1=c(0.4,.5,.5, 0, .8,.8),
                 C2=c(.5,.6,.7, 0, .7,.8), 
                 C3=c(.8,.7,.9, 0, .8,.7), 
                 C4=c(rep(0,6)), 
                 C5=c(0.4,.6,.6, 0, .8,.8),
                 C6=c(0.8,.7,.5, 0, .8,.8), 
                 C7=c(0.8,.6,.4, 0, .8,.8))

row.names(tt) <- paste("F", 1:6, sep='')
tt <- as.matrix(tt)

tt_melt <- melt(tt) 
colnames(tt_melt) <- c('fila', 'columna', 'performance')

tt_melt$cut <- cut(tt_melt$performance, 
                   breaks=c(0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0),
                   labels=as.character(c(0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9)),
                   include.lowest=TRUE)

perf_cols <- c("white", colorRampPalette(c("red", "green"))( 9 ))
perf_text_cols <- c("black", rep("white", 9))

gg <- ggplot(data=tt_melt, aes(x=columna, y=fila, fill=cut))
gg <- gg + geom_tile()
gg <- gg + geom_text(aes(label=performance, color=cut)) 
gg <- gg + labs(title = 'Performance por posicion en el call')
gg <- gg + coord_equal()
gg <- gg + scale_colour_manual(values = perf_text_cols)
gg <- gg + scale_fill_manual(values=perf_cols)
gg <- gg + theme_minimal(base_size = 12, base_family = "")
gg <- gg + theme(legend.position="none")
gg
```

[image]

You should prbly hit up Color Brewer and change the ramp. This method also allows you to ensure the text is visible on the white tiles. Also, `coord_equal` saves you from playing with height/width to get even blocks. You can also add a border to the tiles by adding a `color` (non `aes`) parameter to `geom_tile`.

To keep the `0` values white (per your comment), just use a non `aes` color like you originally did:

```
gg <- ggplot(data=tt_melt, aes(x=columna, y=fila, fill=cut))
gg <- gg + geom_tile()
gg <- gg + geom_text(aes(label=performance), color="white") 
gg <- gg + labs(title = 'Performance por posicion en el call')
gg <- gg + coord_equal()
gg <- gg + scale_fill_manual(values=perf_cols)
gg <- gg + theme_minimal(base_size = 12, base_family = "")
gg <- gg + theme(legend.position="none")
gg
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I only need now to delete the 0 labels in the graph, but keep the rest. Could you also help me with this?

Comment: oh, just change the color to `white`, then. I assumed you actually needed the 0 labels shown. I updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: thanks!!! exactly want I wanted! Can you recommend a simple but complete ggplot tutorial?

Comment: I'd meticulously & deliberately study the [R Graphics Cookbook](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/) to work on fully "think" in ggplot.

Comment: why do you also prefer the `gg <- gg + ...; gg <- gg + ...; gg <- gg + ...` paradigm?

Comment: Completely IMO (acknowledging that I'm 'abnormal' :-) => (a) waaaay easier to manage then accounting for `+` signs on the end of a large plot construction; (b) far less error prone when copying from snippets I have; (c) forces mental ACK that each "grammar phrase" call is powerful enough to warrant standing on it's own; (d) easier to do an interstitial assignment to another variable mid-creation; (e) waaay easier to comment out a plot build step. Of note: I'm as uncomfortable with a string of `+`'s in ggplot as I am a far too long `%>%` pipe in dplyr/magrittr or nested functional parens.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ggplot(data=tt_melt, aes(x=columna, y=fila, fill=performance))+
    geom_tile()+ 
    geom_text(aes(label=performance), color='white') +
    theme_minimal(base_size = 12, base_family = "")+
    labs(title = 'Performance por posicion en el call')+
    scale_colour_manual(values = c("red","yellow", "green"))+
    scale_fill_gradient(low = "yellow",  high = "darkgreen")
```

[image]

There were only typing mistakes in your code. There should be a '+' sign at end of the line if you want to continue to next line in ggplot code.